# Cupy become slower when iterations increase

Tags: python, gpu, cupy

I'm learning to use cupy. But I've found a problem really confusing.  It seems that cupy performs well in a program **at first**. When it runs for a while, Cupy seems be much slower. Here is the code:

```
import cupy as np
from line_profiler import LineProfiler

def test(ary):
    for i in range(1000):
        ary**6

def main():
    rand=np.random.rand(1024,1024)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)

lp = LineProfiler()
lp_wrapper = lp(main)
lp_wrapper()
lp.print_stats()
```

and here is the time performance:

```
Timer unit: 2.85103e-07 s

Total time: 16.3308 s
File: E:\Desktop\test.py
Function: main at line 8

Line #      Hits         Time    Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     8                                             def main():
     9         1    1528817.0  1528817.0      2.7      rand=np.random.rand(1024,1024)
    10         1     111014.0   111014.0      0.2      test(rand)
    11         1      94528.0    94528.0      0.2      test(rand)
    12         1      95636.0    95636.0      0.2      test(rand)
    13         1      94892.0    94892.0      0.2      test(rand)
    14         1    7728318.0  7728318.0     13.5      test(rand)
    15         1   23872383.0 23872383.0     41.7      test(rand)
    16         1   23754666.0 23754666.0     41.5      test(rand)
```

When cupy completed 5000 times of power openrations, it becomes very slow.

I ran this code on Windows, and the cuda version is 10.0

Hope for answers. Thanks you very much!

---

Thanks for your answer! I printed Cupy's memory usage:

```
import cupy as np

def test(ary):
    mempool = cupy.get_default_memory_pool()
    pinned_mempool = cupy.get_default_pinned_memory_pool()
    for i in range(1000):
        ary**6
    print("used bytes: %s"%mempool.used_bytes())
    print("total bytes: %s\n"%mempool.total_bytes())

def main():
    rand=np.random.rand(1024,1024)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
    test(rand)
```

and here is the output:

```
used bytes: 8388608
total bytes: 16777216

used bytes: 8388608
total bytes: 16777216

used bytes: 8388608
total bytes: 16777216

used bytes: 8388608
total bytes: 16777216

used bytes: 8388608
total bytes: 16777216

used bytes: 8388608
total bytes: 16777216

used bytes: 8388608
total bytes: 16777216
```

It seems that the GPU memory usage remain the same during the iteration.

By the way, is there any way to avoid this speed reduction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue of CUDA kernel queue.

See the following:

- https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/1294
- https://github.com/cupy/cupy/issues/1765

The short execution observed in your code was fake, because cupy returns *immediately* when the queue is not filled.

The actual performance was the last line.

**Note:** This was NOT an issue of memory allocation — as I originally suggested in my initial answer — but I include the original answer for the record here.

---

**Original (incorrect) answer**

May be due to the reallocation.

When you `import cupy`, cupy allocates "some mount of" GPU memory. When cupy used all of them, it have to allocate more memory. This increases the execution time.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does cupy provide any way to purge the memory?

Comment: @Colin Please see my post scripts. I'm sorry that I confused you.

Comment: Thank you! My problem is similar to issue 1294. I really appreciate your help!